# How can I overcome the error: Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'Selection<string[]>'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg

The following code was adapted with some help provided for [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790987/how-to-change-d3-legend-entry-spacing-alignment/42795033#427) about how to arrange legend entries. It is working fine for me, except for the last part (the part that should space out the groups). It chokes on the `groups.nodes()`.

I'm getting the error: `[ts] Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'Selection<string[]>'.`

I think this may be happening because I'm using TypeScript. I'm also using d3 v3.5.5.

Any idea how to make this work?

```
        var legendData = [["OA", "yellow", "circle"], ["OI", "blue", "cross"], ["RARC", "green", "diamond"], ["CAPE", "red", "square"], ["Other", "black", "triangle-down"]];

        this.svg.selectAll('.legend').remove() //remove remnants of previous legend so new legend has clean slate...eliminates overlays during resizing

        var svg = d3.select('svg')
            .append('svg').
            attr('width', 800)
            .attr('height', 200);

        var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(legendData)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr("class", "legend");

        var symb = groups.append('path')
            .attr('transform', 'translate ( 15 , 15 )')
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => {
                return d[2]
            }
            ).size((d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.axisFontMultiplier) * (d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.symbolSizeMultiplier)))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            ;

        var text = groups.append('text')
            .attr('y', 20)
            .attr('x', 30)
            .text(function (d) { return d[0]; })
            .style('font-size', function () { return d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.axisFontMultiplier + "px" })
            ;

        // Now space the groups out after they have been appended:
        var padding = 10;
        groups.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (d3.sum(legendData, function (e, j) {
                if (j < i) { return groups.nodes()[j].getBBox().width; } else return 0;
            }) + padding * i) + ",0)";
        })
```

Comment: Since it is TypeScript, the ugly way would be `(<any>groups).nodes()` - I cannot provide a good way since I don't know the whole story, but it would be modifying your `Selection<string[]>` to something more fitted for the group object.

Comment: Thanks @mkaran. I tried your fix but it doesn't seem to work. The error goes away, but the elements don't shift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @mkaran and @Andrew Reid, responding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790987/how-to-change-d3-legend-entry-spacing-alignment/42795033?noredirect=1#comment72740539_42795033), I got to a solution:

```
        // Now space the groups out after they have been appended:
        var padding = 10;
        groups.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (d3.sum(legendData, function (e, j) {
                if (j < i) { return (<any>groups)[0][j].getBBox().width; } else return 0;
            }) + padding * i) + ",0)";
        })
```

Thanks @mkaran and @Andrew Reid!